# Why necessary to convert machine from 50hz to 60hz

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, duty-cycle

I have a machine that is from china and built to run on 50Hz. It consists of several motors, heating elements and related electronic control systems.

What is the reason I cannot just use the machine at us power (60hz)?

I've heard that some times machines built for 50 can run on 60 - is this true? When is it preferible to change the cycles back to 50?

If I should run it on 60hz, what is the cheapest type of solution to impliment myself?

Comment: Hm, it is not obvious if you are aware that it's not only the frequency that differs, but also the voltage.

Comment: @pipe 240VAC/60Hz and 208VAC/60Hz are common in the US for (small) machines.

Answer (score 1):

Most things such as transformers and switching supplies and heaters will run at least as well from 60Hz as from 50Hz, however many motors will run 20% fast and have less torque.

Solutions include replacing the motors, changing gears or pulleys, rewriting to isolate the sensitive bits and using an inverter or using an inverter to power the entire machine. As an alternative to an inverter, a motor-generator set could be used (a 60Hz generator powered by a 50Hz motor). A VFD (variable frequency drive) is essentially an inverter designed to operate a single motor at variable frequency.

If motors are DC, stepper, servo, already have VFD controls the will probably work fine. The situation is a bit worse going in the other direction as 60 Hz-only motors or transformers may overheat on 50Hz, as well as motors running slow.

Comment: So, if I'm looking for a quick black-box solution, would it work for me to build/buy a cheap (~100$ )Variable Frequency Drive to a power supply and use it to supply power to the machine? As far as I can tell, the original use case for a VFD is to supply motors, however, what would be wrong with using it to supply energy to the whole machine?

Comment: VFDs are not designed to operate general loads- they are expecting a fairly inductive load, so I would have no great expectation of success with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

when the machine has synchronous or induction motors and the speed is critical to operation you must convert the frequency. things like electric clocks and phonographs fall into this category.

sometimes the speed is not critical like with a microwave oven turntable, or a cooling fan, if it runs 20%  fast there is no great harm done.

some electronic circuits also require correct frequency, the common LED clock chip "LM8660" is one example.

Comment: the turntable of any "modern" phonograph (post 1970) will be driven by electronics, **not** directly by the power coming from the wall outlet.  now a non-electronic electric clock (do they still make those things?), that's a different story and, at least on the North American side of the pond, the power companies control frequency in such a way that the **integral** (w.r.t. time) of the frequency (literally counting AC cycles) follows legal (NIST) time coming from the atomic clock in Boulder.